# how to enter a date subquery in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

Hello I would like to add an additional column called (DATE), but that does not affect the previously selected data as I could add that column ... (DATE IS IN VARIABLE_VALORES_SMEC), try to do a subquery in the select but it sends me this error: single- row subquery returns more than one row

```
Select  Max(A1.VALOR) AS VALOR ,

(SELECT FECHA AS FC FROM VARIABLE_VALORES_SMEC WHERE ID_AGENTE IN A1.ID_AGENTE <--here is the problem
) MES,

(SELECT  CODIGO_AGENTE   FROM AGENTES WHERE ID_AGENTE = A1.ID_AGENTE 
) Agentess,
(SELECT  NOMBRE_AGENTE   FROM AGENTES WHERE ID_AGENTE = A1.ID_AGENTE 
) Nombre_Agente
 
FROM VARIABLE_VALORES_SMEC A1


WHERE A1.VALOR < '1'
AND A1.VALOR != '0'

AND A1.ID_AGENTE IN (SELECT C1.ID_AGENTE FROM  VARIABLE_VALORES_SMEC C1
WHERE A1.FECHA =  C1.FECHA) 


AND A1.ID_AGENTE  IN (SELECT B1.ID_AGENTE 
FROM AGENTES B1
WHERE ID_CATEGORIA_AGENTE = 'AC006'
)


AND (A1.FECHA between (ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(:FECHAIN,'MM/DD/YYYY'),-1)) AND (LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(:FECHAIN, 'MM/DD/YYYY'),-1))))
AND A1.ID_VARIABLE LIKE '%_calc_total_pot@%'



 GROUP BY ID_AGENTE
```

Answer (score 1):

> single- row subquery returns more than one row

This error means that your subquery returns more than 1 row (replace FECHA with count(*) and you will see how many rows does it return), so you need:

1. aggregate returned values, for example using listagg() function, ie:

   (select listagg(FECHA)within group(order by 1) from ...

or
2. analyze your predicates in the subquery so that returns just 1 row.

PS. To make your queries more clear and readable, it would be better to use aliases for all tables and columns, for example

```
(SELECT sq1.FECHA AS FC FROM VARIABLE_VALORES_SMEC sq1 WHERE sq1.ID_AGENTE IN A1.ID_AGENTE) MES,
```

PS2. Don't use IN for single value, just use "="

Answer (score 1):

Your column `FECHA` is from table `VARIABLE_VALORES_SMEC` on which your main query is executing, then why don't you simply use direct column instead of subquery as follows:

```
Select  Max(A1.VALOR) AS VALOR ,
        Max(FECHA) keep (dense_rank last order by value) AS MES
   .....
   .....
```

Comment: Becausewould I have to group (DATE) and that would bring me much more data than I need,
If I have 12 data as a result, I just want to see the date of the 12 data that was executed

Comment: Yes, then 12th data must have max fecha, is it correct?

Comment: No, friend ... I need the Date of the maximum medicine Obtained

I mean the Date of max (value)

but not the maximum date